# How to keep idiomatic ("" > None) expression from python 2 in python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.4, six

I have code that relies on python 2 typing feature

```
result1 = result_or_None (...)
result2 = result_or_None (...)

final = max (result1, result2)
```

Problem is - python 3 doesn't support `"Result string" > None` comparison so the code returns run-time exception. Python 2 supports this well. Is there way to implement this idiomatically (e.g. without explicitly enumerating all None cases)?

This also uses idea from functional programming (None as bottom value) - bit disappointing not to see it in python3 (what was the rationale for removing this?)

Comment: Why this was done? Because the ordering of `None` compared to other types was *arbitrary*, as was any intra-type ordering. It certainly never was meant to be used as a 'bottom' value. You could use `float('-inf')` to signify a bottom numeric value instead.

Comment: Your variables are strings and you want to get the first string that is defined, and if both of them are None, then None as a result? `final = result1 or result2`. This will work for any values that are considered truthy.

Comment: Good to know! I guess the  `"" > None` worked just 'by chance'.
+1 for the `final = result1 or result2`, it seems to be correct idiomatic way to do things. Thanks!